# Node request module - sample get request failing

Tags: javascript, node-request, get-request

Vaguely following this 'tutorial': https://stackabuse.com/the-node-js-request-module/

I get to the alert ('Options Declared'), but then my program stops at the request and I have no idea why.

```
const request = require('request');
function testGet(){

    alert("Get test started");

    const options = {  

        url: "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json",
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
            'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'

        }
    }

    alert("Options declared");

    request(options, function(err, res, body){

        let json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json);

    });

    alert("Get test done");
}
```

Comment: can you console err in request..
I mean put a console.log(err) and share it here

Comment: it should not stop at request. It will move on and print "Get test done". And also, how are you executing alert? have you written a custom method console.log?

Answer (score 1):

Just send the response and error as the response object and look at what comes.

```
const request = require('request');
    function testGet(){

        alert("Get test started");

        const options = {  

            url: "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json",
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
                'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'

            }
        }

        alert("Options declared");

        request(options, function(err, res, body){
          res.json({err : err, result: body});
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You place the request function declaration and body inside testGet().

Please do that outside the testGet() like this.

```
function testGet(){
  alert("Get test started");

  const options = {  

    url: "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'

    }
  }

  alert("Options declared");

  request.post(options, callback);
}

request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
    let json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
    alert("Get test done");
});
```